# IOS 15 beta 2 and beta 3. issue with WKwebview loadFileURL: allowingReadAccessToURL:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode13, ios15

I am trying to load HTML file and give access to WEBVIEW to the folder where all the assets are present.

```
[self.webView loadFileURL:URL allowingReadAccessToURL:folderURL];
```

the HTML file is loaded but no assets are getting loaded. this is happening only on the iOS 15 beta versions. Have any one had similar issues??

Comment: What do you expect from beta versions?  Share the issue at Apple's developer forums.

Comment: @ElTomato I already did. thanks :)